# Disabling System services in Rooted android device

Tags: android, performance, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm working on disabling the Telephony, Sensor and Location services in our android device as they are not needed for our devices. As i found from some articles, based on the system properties set, android system do not start them. But i didn't find where the respective system properties set in the android system.

Can any one please tell me where can i modify in order to not to start the above mentioned services ?

If we disable them what could be the impact on other system default apps ?